# How to end android service after ASyncTask it spun off completes?

Tags: java, android, service, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have a Downloader Service that loads a list of downloads to run from my database.

It then creates an ASyncTask that will run the downloads in a background Thread.

This all works perfectly well, but the problem is I don't currently have a way to tell the service that the Downloader has completed.  I somehow have to send the service a message from the ASyncTask's [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) function (which runs on the UIThread).

I can't simply close the service remotely because the Service has some work to do when the ASyncTask completes.

I've considered registering a listener from the service and calling it in onPostExecute, but I think this would cause problems like closing the service before the Task was complete or some threadlocking issues.

How can I send a message (like a broadcast intent) to my Downloader service from my ASyncTask?

**EDIT**
Here's some code for those of you confused about what I am doing.

DownloadService.java (Important bits):

```
public class DownloadService extends Service implements OnProgressListener {

/** The Downloads. */
private List<Download> mDownloads = new ArrayList<Download>(10);

private DownloadTask mDownloadTask;

/** The Intent receiver that handles broadcasts. */
private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        DebugLog.i(TAG, "onRecieve" +intent.toString());
        handleCommand(intent);
    }

};

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Service#onCreate()
 */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    DebugLog.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    IntentFilter commandFilter = new IntentFilter();
    commandFilter.addAction(ACTION_PAUSE_DOWNLOADS);
    commandFilter.addAction(ACTION_START_DOWNLOADS);
    registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, commandFilter);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Service#onDestroy()
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    DebugLog.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    //Make sure all downloads are saved and stopped
    pauseAllDownloads();
    //unregister command receiver
    unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
    //cancel notifications
    closeNotification();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Service#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)
 */a
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
/**
 * Handle command sent via intent.
 * <strong>Warning, this function shouldn't do any heavy lifting.  
 * This will be run in UI thread and should spin off ASyncTasks to do work.</strong>
 *
 * @param intent the intent
 */
private void handleCommand(Intent intent) {
    if(intent != null){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if(action.equals(ACTION_START_DOWNLOADS))
        {
            updateDownloads();//Fetch list of downloads to do from database
            startDownloads();//run downloads
        }else if(action.equals(ACTION_PAUSE_DOWNLOADS)){
            pauseAllDownloads();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Start all downloads currently in list (in order).
 */
private void startDownloads()
{
    pauseAllDownloads();//make sure we don't have a download task running
    mDownloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    mDownloadTask.setOnProgressListener(this);
    Download[] downloads = new Download[mDownloads.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i<mDownloads.size(); i++)
    {
        Download d = mDownloads.get(i);
        if(d.getStatus() != Download.COMPLETE)
        {
            downloads[i] = mDownloads.get(i);   
        }
    }
    //must be called on UI thread
    mDownloadTask.execute(downloads);
}

/**
 * Pause downloads.
 */
private void pauseAllDownloads()
{
    if(mDownloadTask == null)
    {
        //Done.  Nothing is downloading.
        return;
    }

    //Cancel download task first so that it doesn't start downloading next
    if(mDownloadTask.cancel(true))
    {
        //Task has been canceled.  Pause the active download.
        Download activeDownload = mDownloadTask.getActiveDownload();
        if(activeDownload != null)
        {
            activeDownload.pause();
        }
    }else
    {
        if(mDownloadTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        {
            DebugLog.w(TAG, "Download Task Already Finished");
        }else{
            //Task could not be stopped
            DebugLog.w(TAG, "Download Task Could Not Be Stopped");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onProgress(Download download) {
    //download progress is reported here from DownloadTask
}
}
```

DownloadTask:

```
/**
 * The Class DownloadTask.
 */
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Download, Download, Void> {

/** The On progress listener. */
private OnProgressListener mOnProgressListener;

/**
 * The listener interface for receiving onProgress events.
 * The class that is interested in processing a onProgress
 * event implements this interface and registers it with the component.
 *
 */
public static interface OnProgressListener
{

    /**
     * On progress update.
     *
     * @param download the download
     */
    public void onProgress(Download download);
}

private Download mCurrent;

/**
 * Sets the on progress listener.
 *
 * @param listener the new on progress listener
 */
public void setOnProgressListener(OnProgressListener listener)
{
    mOnProgressListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Gets the active download.
 *
 * @return the active download
 */
public Download getActiveDownload()
{
    return mCurrent;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
 */
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Download... params) {
    int count = params.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        mCurrent = params[i];
        if(mCurrent == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        mCurrent.setDownloadProgressListener(new Download.OnDownloadProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadProgress(Download download, int bytesDownloaded,
                    int bytesTotal) {
                publishProgress(download);
            }
        });
        mCurrent.setOnStatusChangedListener(new Download.OnStatusChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(Download download, int status) {
                publishProgress(download);
            }
        });
        mCurrent.download();
        //publishProgress(mCurrent); redundant call
        if(this.isCancelled())
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
 */
public void onPostExecute(Void v)
{
    //TODO notify completion.
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
 */
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Download... progress) {
    if(mOnProgressListener != null)
    {
        for(Download d:progress)
        {
            mOnProgressListener.onProgress(d);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post some example code. It's not quite clear how the Service and AsyncTask are working together. Usually you need one or the other but not both.

Comment: I'll post code in a bit, but to answer your question my service manages what is getting downloaded without requiring an activity to be in the foreground, and the ASyncTask actually does the heavy lifting in the background (since a service doesn't do that automatically).  I could have spun off a Runnable on a thread from the service, but ASyncTask manages the threads more easily.

Comment: AsyncTask's onPostExecute runs after doInBackground, so the relative order is ensured. But I also don't get why you need to use an AsyncTask from within the service. Could you explain more?

Comment: @Heiko Rupp @Robby Pond A Service isn't a separate thread.  To do my heavy lifting network communication, I need to spin off another thread FROM my service to do the work, otherwise the UI will lock and I get ANR.  ASyncTask provides a simple way of creating managing this new thread.

Comment: Why not just send an Intent to the service to notify it that the download is complete? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @WorkerThread I thought about that and think it's a good plan, but I couldn't figure out how to pull that off.  The ASyncTask doesn't have a valid context from which to broadcast that intent.  I could pass the context but that's a memory leak waiting to happen, since the context holds references to basically EVERYTHING.

Comment: One can use weak reference to avoid memory leak

Answer (score 6):

> I have a Downloader Service that loads a list of downloads to run from my database.
>   It then creates an ASyncTask that will run the downloads in a background Thread.

Why not just use an `IntentService`, considering that it already has a background thread for you? [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/Downloader) demonstrating using an `IntentService` for downloads.

> I don't currently have a way to tell the service that the Downloader has completed.

Call `stopSelf()` from `onPostExecute()`. Better yet, use `IntentService`, which will automatically shut down when there is no more work to be done.

Comment: Like I said, I don't want to automatically shut down the service.  The service needs to know when the Downloads have completed, report their progress (On the UIThread), and then DECIDE if more work is to be done, before shutting ITSELF down.  Besides, using an ASyncTask allows much easier updates to the UIThread from the worker thread and doesn't require dealing with messengers for frequent communication between my threads.

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile: "Like I said, I don't want to automatically shut down the service" -- I didn't say you were. " The service needs to know when the Downloads have completed, report their progress (On the UIThread), and then DECIDE if more work is to be done, before shutting ITSELF down." -- which is accomplished by calling `stopSelf()`. "Besides, using an ASyncTask allows much easier updates to the UIThread from the worker thread and doesn't require dealing with messengers for frequent communication between my threads." -- your service should not be doing much of anything on the "UIThread".

Comment: I'm reading your post that I should call stopSelf from onPostExecute.  My understanding is this would just stop the service, not tell the service to DECIDE whether or not it should be shut down.  According to the docs, it's the same as calling stopService. Also, there's another disadvantage of IntentService.  It holds all other commands until the intent has been finished.  This means that another mechanism must be introduced to pause, resume, restart, or otherwise control the download process.

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile: "My understanding is this would just stop the service, not tell the service to DECIDE whether or not it should be shut down." -- call `stopSelf()` from wherever floats your proverbial boat, then. "This means that another mechanism must be introduced to pause, resume, restart, or otherwise control the download process." -- true. You need to decide whether having those features is worth the code complexity that you are apparently having difficulty with.